Portable SSD not automounting in 24.10
After upgrading from 24.04 to 24.10, my portable Samsung T7 (Ext4) no longer automounts when I plug it in to the usb port.
When I plug it in, the name of the drive will appear in files/nautilus, but the eject symbol will not appear and programs cannot access it. When I click on the name of drive it will then mount.
However,if I plug in a thumbdrive (Fat32), it automounts perfectly.
How should I try and fix this?
Edit: I also tried 'Disks' and overrode the normal session setting plus turned on 'automount at start up' for the drive but that didn't work.

First off, verify that the drive is actually unmounted:
mount | grep -F "/media/$(id -un)"

As on 24.04 (Nautilus 46.2) I'm experiencing a bug where regardless of the mount state of the drive, Nautilus will always show external drives as mounted. Which is the opposite of what you're experiencing, but, well, I don't expect a bug to behave consistently.
But if the drive really is unmounted, then it could be a case of org.gnome.desktop.media-handling.automount set to false; make sure org.gnome.desktop.media-handling.automount is set to true:
% gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount 
true

And if it's not, set it to true:
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount true

And unplug / re-plug the drive, again verifying the drive's mount state using mount | grep -F "/media/$(id -un)" to avoid being mislead by the possible bug.

So here is what I found so far...
I inserted the drive into the USB and nautilis showed the name.
I then ran
mount | grep -F "/media/$(id -un)"
and got nothing.
Back in nautilus, I clicked on the drive's name.
I ran the command 'mount' again and got
/dev/sde1 on /media/abc/Data Backup type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,errors=remount-ro,stripe=8191,uhelper=udisks2)
so clearly it is not automounting.
Tried:
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount
and got a 'true' response. Which is somewhat odd.
On 24.04 it still automounts perfectly, must be gnome.

@Worn-out_home-tech Weird, it does sound like a bug. I suggest filing a bug on Launchpad, I quickly (very quickly) checked and it doesn't seem like anyone reported this yet

Bug lodged as new issue.

Your flash is recognized as "media" and so automounts under /media//.  The SSD is recognized as a disk, so does whatever the /etc/fstab entry has for it -- a mount point, and options, which may include auto or noauto.
Edit the fstab file, add a line for your ssd to mount it wherever you want (/mnt/xxx is  usual place). and ensure the options don't prevent automounting (defaults,auto will certainly allow automounting, maybe "auto" is optional).

I guess with 99% certainty that this user's SSD drive is not in the users /etc/fstab. My first assumption is that this is a (in my opinion undesired) change in the default behavior of the newest Gnome, where (indeed perhaps only media that are recognized as a hard drive rather than an USB stick) are not anymore automounted.

I tried your suggestion and you are right in that there was no fstab entry.
However, using Disks, I created an entry with automount on start up and it did not work if I plug the drive in after start up. 'auto' was definitely in there.
I also tried it without the automount at startup with the auto entry and it still didn't work.
